# Captcha for all reviews?

Tags: feature-request, review, captcha, robots

If automated (non-human) bots are being used for reviews, why don't we add captcha to every review?

The effort of solving a captcha is much less than the typical effort of properly performing a review, so adding captcha shouldn't cause much impedance.

The audit should of course remain, because that is about ensuring *quality*. Captcha is about ensuring its not a bot.

Comment: Not all reviews. That would be a *huge* hassle. Maybe every X reviews

Comment: Captcha is just annoying, and it's gotten to the point where not even humans can solve it. I always have to refresh the damn thing like 10 times before I get something that's actually legible... I -1 anything that involves implementing *more* Captcha. Just no.

Comment: This is not about non-human bots. This is about *humans* not paying attention, just wanting to collect the badges. A captcha would just annoy **everyone**, including the good reviewers.

Comment: Captcha is a burden for legit user's...

Comment: Let's captcha every time you want to watch a YouTube video?

Comment: Are we actually having problems with non-human bots? Though we sometimes call them "robo reviewers", they are as far as I know all human.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm pretty sure forcing people to fill in a captcha for every review they make would put almost everyone off from ever reviewing anything and ultimately clog the system up completely.

Considering it already takes more than one person to affect the outcome of a review, and there are also fake test audits in place to catch such bots out, I don't think a captcha would be needed here at all.

If there was ever a dire situation where a load of audits were slipping through the net then I'm sure a new review type could be set up to allow people review other reviews - I imagine that would be much more favourable throughout the community than captchas! ;-)